# Dealing with Nulls from a DataReader

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset

I have done this in the past, but I cant remember the correct way to deal with DBNULLS.

This is vb.net

The error im getting is Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Here is the code.

```
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
Do While reader.Read
Dim item As New clsProvider(reader.Item("MasterAccountID"), reader.Item("CompanyName"), reader.Item("Address"), reader.Item("Postcode"), reader.Item("Telephone"), reader.Item("Fax"), reader.Item("Number_of_Companies"), reader.Item("Total_Number_of_employees"), reader.Item("MainContactName"), reader.Item("MainContactPhone"), reader.Item("MainContactEmail"), reader.Item("Fee"), Convert.ToString(reader.Item("Notes")))
            list.Add(item)
Loop
reader.Close()
```

The issue i have is that some of the items may be empty in the DB. I'm sure in the past I have done something like

```
convert.ToString(reader.item("Something")
```

But for the life of me i cant remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
 reader.item("Something").ToString()
```

is what you've done before?

This isn't necessarily *correct* but it does deal with null strings quite effectively.

Comment: Correct that is what i have done before...
Any suggestions on how it should be handled?

Comment: Depends what you want to do. You can check with `reader.IsDBNull("something")` but if you're happy with null strings being replaced with empty strings, the above is going to work. Depends how purist you're feeling

Comment: Its a quick prototype im developing to hand off to someone who has a clue :D so this is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the column is nullable, then you should check for null:

```
If (reader.IsDBNull(ordinal))
```

See [IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.isdbnull.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
IFF(reader.item("Something") != DBNull.Value, reader.item("Something"), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check if the column value is null (check the incoming value for DBNull). Once you know that you can decide what to do next - assign null or some other default value to your variable.

I am not sure if my VB.Net is still upto the mark but something like this should help:

```
Dim item As New clsProvider
item.AccountId = TryCast(reader.Item("MasterAccountID"), String)
item.SomeInt= If(TryCast(reader.Item("SomeInt"), System.Nullable(Of Integer)), 0)
```

Use `TryCast` to check if cast is possible.